# WatchKit menu item not showing on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit

I added a menu to my watchkit app containing one menu item. In my simulator the item shows up perfectly when simulating a force touch. On my real Apple Watch on the other hand a force touch is recognized, the app gets blurry but no button to press.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug?

My action linked to the button only contains the following:

```
@IBAction func menuButtonRefresh() {
    setup()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually because the app can't find the custom image for your button. Is your image included in the WatchKit App bundle? Unfortunately, Interface Builder allows you to use an image from any bundle, but it won't work on a real device.

Comment: That was it... can't believe I didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Another little issue might happen to anyone on real watch:**
I had the same problem. I used **system** items. I long press my finger, but nothing happened.
All you have to do press your finger **stronger**. ;)